# Tabs Resize Doesn't Work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've tried several snippets of code I've found from various sources, including Facebook itself and stackoverflow, but none of them work to increase the default length of the custom tabs I created for a client. I've listed the methods I've tried below.

One variable I haven't been able to play with is the Canvas Height setting described on Facebook's FB.Canvas.setSize page. It is nowhere to be found on my App Dashboard. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/

It says: "Note: this method is only enabled when Canvas Height is set to "Settable (Default: 800px)" in the App Dashboard."

And here are the various methods I've tried to resize.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({appId: '215615521792601', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

<!-- EACH OF THESE THREE LINES BELOW WAS TRIED ONE AT A TIME.-->
FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(true);
//  FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(true);
// FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: 1576 });
 };
```

And here is another method I found:

```
<!-- FACEBOOK TAB LENGTH FIX HEADER START -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- FACEBOOK TAB LENGTH FIX HEADER END -->

<!-- FACEBOOK TAB LENGTH FIX BODY START --> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.Canvas.setAutoResize( 100 );
}
// Do things that will sometimes call sizeChangeCallback()
function sizeChangeCallback() {
FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: 2400 });
}
</script>    
<!-- FACEBOOK TAB LENGTH FIX BODY END -->
```

Thanks for any and all help! I'm completely stumped and frustrated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canvas Height option is available in "*App on Facebook*" section under **Basic** Settings in App Dashboard.

Comment: Am I looking in the wrong place then? Here's a screenshot of my app's Basic Settings page. 

http://graphish.com/test/fb_problem.png

Comment: You are looking at right place. In your screenshot,below Page tab where you have filled you page details you have (*Website with facebook login** below which you have **Apps on facebook** tab. Canvas height settings is inside that tab.